# What's the use of multiple asterisks in the function call?

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers, dereference, function-call

I can't think of any practical use of multiple asterisks in the function call:

```
void foo(int a, char b)
{

}

int main(void)
{
    (**************foo)(45, 'c');

    //or with pointer to function:
    void (*ptr)(int, char) = foo;
    (******ptr)(32, 'a');
}
```

Why is this thing allowed both in C and C++?

Comment: It's explicitly allowed for the sake of C obfuscated code contests.

Comment: probably the original coder was being payed per character of code rather than per line

Comment: @TomTanner Can't you even put newlines between the asterisks? That would really be great ;)

Comment: you can put as much white space in there as you like

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Why is this thing allowed both in C and C++?

I can't speak for C++, but for C at least a function designator is converted to a pointer:

> 6.3.2.1 - 4
>
> A **function designator** is an expression that has function type. Except
>   when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary & operator,
>   a function designator with type ‘‘function returning type’’ is
>   converted to an expression that has type ‘‘**pointer to function
>   returning type**’’.

Applying the indirection operator yields a function designator:

> 6.5.3.2 - 3
>
> The unary * operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a
>   function, the result is a **function designator**

So no matter how many times you apply the indirection operator you'll get the same thing: a function designator that's immediately converted to a pointer.

---

In my opinion there's little or no use in doing this.

Answer (score 43):

One of the standard conversions, in both C and C++, is the function-to-pointer conversion; when a function name appears in an expression, it can be converted into a pointer to that function. So:

- `foo` is equivalent to `&foo`
- `*foo` is equivalent to `*(&foo)`, or `foo`
- `**foo` is eqivalent to `**(&foo)`, or `*foo`, or `foo`

and so on.

This means that you can legally add as many `*` as you like before a function name without changing its meaning. There's no reason to do that, though.

Answer (score 9):

Because the `*` operator expects an address value. And whenever a value is expected (as opposed to an object or function glvalue), the lvalue to rvalue, function to pointer and array to pointer conversions are applied on an operand. So the dereferenced function immediately again converts to a pointer when again dereferenced.

These all either read values from objects or produce a pointer value that refers to the beginning of an array or function respectively.

These rows of dereferences have no purpose other than for the lulz of it.

Answer (score -4):

The way i understand it is

```
* is a pointer to a memory address
& is the value at the Memory address

*foo means pointer to foo memory address
**foo means *(*foo) *(foo memory address) This is a different value from *foo
```

it continues like that...